# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined [antdesign - switch]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I want to use the event as callback in the antd's switch.
I don't know how to get the value of `this.state.game` using event.

```
handleToggle = event => {
     this.setState({
         [event.target.name]: !this.state[event.target.name]
     });
};

   render() {
     return(
        <Switch 
            checkedChildren='on' 
            unCheckedChildren='off' 
            name='game' value={this.state.game} 
            onClick={this.handleToggle}
        />
    );
}
```

Comment: @JosephD. sorry i edited the code already. It's correct on my code but it's still not working

Comment: are you calling onClick function passed to Switch component in async?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Switch](https://ant.design/components/switch/) `onClick` signature is:

```
Function(checked: boolean, event: Event)
```

So it should be:

```
handleToggle = (_, event) => {
  this.setState({
    [event.target.name]: !this.state[event.target.name]
  });
}
```

i.e `event` is the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to add prop `value` to `Switch`.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    game: false
  };

  handleToggle = (checked, event) => {
    this.setState({
      game: checked
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { game } = this.state;
    console.log("switch status: ", game);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Switch
          defaultChecked={false}
          checkedChildren="on"
          unCheckedChildren="off"
          name="game"
          onClick={this.handleToggle}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

here is a quick demo [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-sun-mq0ud)

Comment: I want to use the "event" as callback. Not the value directly.

Comment: @cmll I have updated my code.  as per antd switch `onChange`  is ```Function(checked: boolean, event: Event)```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I was not getting form instance correctly:

```js
const form = Form.useForm();
```

You need to destructure it like so:

```js
const [form] = Form.useForm();
```